# Как удалить текстовые значения в ячейке xslx с помощью pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

[image: Вот пример]Есть большой xslx файл (пример привёл ниже). Вопрос: как мне **удалить в файле** все строки, в одной ячейке которой, есть слово **"Итог"**? Нужно именно **удалить, а не отфильтровать**)) никак не могу понять как нужно написать условие((
Файл огромный (около 7Мб), поэтому не хочу пользоваться топором в виде текстового редактора excell.

Comment: Вам нужно чтоб в ячейках со строками, вместо строк, появилось NaN(пустая ячейка)?

Comment: Или вам нужно в столбце, в котором есть ячейка со словом «итог» удалить все ячейки со строками?

Comment: мне нужно удалить всю строку, где хоть в одной ячейке которой, есть слово "Итог"

Comment: Слово "итог" встречается только в одном столбце, как в примере, или может быть в любом столбце?

Comment: Слово "итог" может быть в любом столбце

Answer (score 2):

Я не совсем считываю весь контекст вашего вопроса, поэтому я опишу для вас общий примерный процесс того, как удаляются строки из `xlsx` файла посредством `pandas`.

Представим у нас есть следующая таблица `kek.xlsx`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы хотим, допустим, удалить из неё строки в котором поле `age` больше `30` и пересохранить её, например, в `kek2.xlsx`. Для этого мы можем использовать следующий код:

```
import pandas as pd

# Загрузка файла Excel в DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('01.06.23\kek.xlsx')

# Условие для удаления строк
condition = df['age'] > 30

# Удаление строк, удовлетворяющих условию
df = df[~condition]

# Сохранение измененного DataFrame в файл Excel
df.to_excel('01.06.23\kek2.xlsx', index=False)
```

В результате программы будет создан файл `kek2.xlsx`, вот как он будет выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

UPD

Для того чтобы проверять по строке, можно присвоить переменной `condition` следующее значение:

```
condition = df['ваша ячейка'].str.contains('Итог')
```

Comment: привёл пример, я уже сталкивался с примером подобным вашему, но у меня немного другое

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то это должно сработать:

```py
df['Столбец'] = df['Столбец'].apply(lambda x: x if type(x) != str else None)
```

Это должно удалить все значения ячеек, в которых тип данных — строка.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос в этот раз, вот код, который будет проверять наличие слова "Итог" в столбце "Город" и отфильтровывать датафрейм так, что там будут оставаться только те строки, где нет слова "Итог":

```
df['Город'] = df['Город'].apply(lambda x: x.split())

def has_itog(array):
    return 'Итог' in array

df = df[~df['Город'].apply(has_itog)].copy()
df['Город'] = df['Город'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
df = df.reset_index()
```

На выходе будет датафрейм со строками без слова "Итог"