# Как выборочно удалить строки по частичному текстовому соответствию из ячейки pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть большой xslx файл (краткий пример привёл ниже). Вопрос: как мне удалить в файле все строки, где хотя бы в одной ячейке которых, есть слово "Итог"? Нужно именно удалить, а не отфильтровать, без оставления пустой строки)) никак не могу понять как нужно написать условие(( Файлы огромные (около 7Мб), поэтому не хочу постоянно пользоваться топором в виде текстового редактора excel.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем здесь pandas, почему не использовать VBA прямо в Excel?

Comment: потому что файлов много, весят также много и каждый раз использовать VBA не предоставляется возможным

Comment: Код на VBA создаете только один раз, а примените его ко всем файлам (в цикле).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить текстовые значения в ячейке xslx с помощью pandas?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1523292/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b5-xslx-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-pandas)

Comment: Это мой же вопрос, на который нет ответа. Если вы знаете знаете как написать код на vba. то буду благодарен, если вы им поделитесь, потому что я не знаю как "написать код на VBA и применить его ко всем файлам в цикле"

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает ответ на предыдущий ваш вопрос?

Comment: и у вас странное понимание термина "отфильтровать". Отфильтровать - значит оставить, в данном случае, нужные строки. причем здесь какие-то "пустые строки"?

Comment: Предпочёл бы конструктивные ответы и комментарии, а не "сделай вот так, но код и пример показывать не буду, это же легко". Если у вас нет конструктивного сообщения без критики, то пожалуйста не читайте, минусуйте и идите дальше. Спасибо.

Comment: я вам задал вопрос: чем вас не устроил ответ на предыдущий вопрос. я хочу понять, что вами движет при повторении вопроса, чтобы его не закрыть как дубликат. если хотите конструктивного ответа, задавайте конструктивные вопросы. Итак, чем вас не устроил ответ на предыдущий аналогичный вопрос?

Comment: Данный ответ не подходит и не решает мою проблему. Я думал что сообщество stack не похоже на habr, однако видимо, исключения есть.

Comment: не стоит транслировать свою неспособность задать нормальный вопрос на сообщество. перефразирую (третья попытка): _почему_ тот ответ не решает проблему? что он делает не так? почему пользователи должны давать кучу разных решений, пытаясь угадать, что же вам все-таки нужно?

Comment: Уважаемый комментатор, загляните пожалуйста в мой аккаунт и там вы увидите, что я только недавно начал изучать анализ и питон. Я думаю, что это естественно - когда человек с 2,5 месяцами программирования, который старается изучать предмет сам, не знает каких-то идиом. Если у вас есть чему научить, то прошу помощи, если нет, то закрываем обсуждение и идём по своим делам.

Comment: @Voort Если вы пришли сюда за советами опытных людей, то вот это они и есть. В том числе советы о том, как нужно формулировать вопросы, чтобы на них могли ответить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учитывая инфу из вашего предыдущего вопроса по этой теме, что 'Итог' может быть в любом столбце:

```
cols = ['Город', 'Заказы'] # с помощью df.columns получаем все столбцы и вставляем их в список

def has_itog(array):
    return 'Итог' in array

for i in cols:
    df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: x.split())
    df = df[~df[i].apply(has_itog)].copy()
    df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
    
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Единственное-столбцы с числами (если там тоже встречается Итог (если не встречается, то не указываем эти столбцы в список `cols`)) должны содержать строки(`str`), а не `int`/`float`, после выполнения отброса строк с Итогом, можно вернуть нужным столбцам тип дынных `int`/`float`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Voort не за что!)

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа такого:

```py
df = df[~df['A'].str.contains('Итог')]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Загрузка файла Excel в DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')

# Перебор строк и удаление строк, в которых есть слово "Итог"
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'Итог' in row.values:
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)

# Сохранение обновленного DataFrame обратно в файл Excel
df.to_excel('example_filtered.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста - как удалить именно строки?

Comment: Попробуйте так…

Comment: Нельзя в цикле удалять что-то их объекта, по которому вы итерируетесь. В данном случае будет просто неэффективно, а вообще лучше так никогда не делать.